# Lambda expression assistance

Tags: c#, linq, lambda

Im trying to query a List but unable to get the result the way i would like, im kinda new to linq so im sure this will be quite easy for you guys.

**Object:**

```
public class myObject
{
    public string Date { get; set; }
    public string Log { get; set; }
}
```

The List i would like to query comes from:

```
public List<myObject> getMyObjects()
{
    // Code to get objects, ill leave it out here and return new list for this example
    return new List<myObject>();
}
```

The result i would like to get is a list with distinct dates and the number of logs on each date, ill provide my bad attempt below

```
var result = (from data in errorList
                     select new 
                     {
                        datum = data.Datum.Distinct(),
                        antal = data.Felkod
                     }).GroupBy(x => x.datum);
```

How would i do this the correct way? Help would be much appreciated

Answer (score 5, accepted):

```
var query = errorList.GroupBy(x => x.Date)
                     .Select(g => new { Date = g.Key, Count = g.Count() });
```

or

```
var query = from error in errorList
            group error by error.Date into g
            select new {
                Date = g.Key,
                Count = g.Count()
            };
```

Comment: Its just amazing how easy it looks when someone gets it right, thanx alot !

Comment: If you can just edit the first formula, its missing the ending } before the last )